# Percentage never to be 100% unless actually 100%

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, string-formatting, percentage

In a report, our client can have more than 100 000 items that are checked and in the report metadata (xml file) want a 2-decimal percentage of how many of the items were "checked OK".

However, the number should not be 100% unless actually everything is ok. Due to the number of items, the standard math operations and String.Format() can do that rounding error.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

The client accepts that 99.99% is a special case that covers 99.999999999% even though it is mathematically incorrect.

The important thing is that the report data does not show 100% when there are items that did not check out ok.

Comment: My thought would instead of passing percentage, pass items done+passed so if != then its never 100.. even if it says is, round down and all that.

Comment: Without have seen any code example or such, if you are using double as a number, use decimal instead (Which are not a float number type)

Comment: @Hypnobrew: `decimal` is still a floating point type. It's just a decimal floating point type rather than a binary floating point type.

Comment: This question might be better off at the User Experience Stack Exchange. What I would question: If the majority of items will be ok, is a percentage in any way useful in the first place? Wouldn't it make more sense to say "7 items failed to check out"?

Comment: Yes, it would make more sense to report errors or the respective counts. However, it is a report-in-report executive summary type of thing. It is silly that double/decimal percentage is passed as preformatted string in the xml. Otherwise, I could pass the buck.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a little helper method?

```
public double GetPercentage(int checkedOk, int total)
{
    if (checkedOk == total)
        return 100.0;

     var percentage = (100.0 * checkedOk) / total;
     return percentage > 99.99 ? 99.99: percentage;
}
```

I'd remove the magic number ‘99.99` but you get the idea.